# How to build a system to auto create paragraphs of text based on basic data

Tags: artificial-intelligence

For example, given a basketball box score with the final score and the score at the end of each of the quarters, it could put together a summary of sorts:

> Wildcats Win Close Game!
>   Despite a late charge by the Flying Eagles, the Wildcats hold on to win by 2.
>   The Wildcats started the game behind, though a surge through the middle of the
>   game put them ahead at the start of the fourth quarter. But then the Flying
>   Eagles put on the pressure late, though in the end, it wasn't enough.

I obviously don't want to build a huge `if` statement for every possible case, and I'm fine if the stories are identical for similar data sets.  I don't have a language preference, mostly I'm curious about how to build something about this. References, keywords to search on, or places to learn this kinda thing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for "boilerplate text generator".  Generally, you put markers in the boilerplate text, like <homeTeam>.  You then do a search and replace of the markers.

Comment: More I'm looking for of a way to flow the text based on the scores, not just the team names.  Eg: if it's a blowout, or a close game the whole way, or the game was a big upset.  My use case isn't sports, but it's easier to give an example using sports.

Comment: Then you have to write code.  I suppose you could train a neural network to spit out different text for different game situations, but I suspect it would be simpler to write code.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of the need to write code :-)  What I'm looking for are patterns for solving this kind of problem that have already been found.